# How to get an Observable<number> from a reduce operation on another Observable in Nativescript Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, reduce

I'm trying to show an observable **total** in my angular component like this:

```
total$ | async
```

It should be the sum of a calculation on all lines in a shopping basket:

```
totalAmount = sum of (price * unitsOrdered)
```

My interfaces are:

```
export interface IBasketLine {
    unitsOrdered?: number;
    price?: number;
}
export interface IBasket {
    header?: IBasketHeader;
    lines?: Array<IBasketLine>;
}
```

My Angular component contains **2 observables**:

```
basket$: Observable<IBasket>;
nettoTotal$: Observable<number>;
```

The observable basket$ is initialized from my ngrx store and all lines are visible in my view.  This is my **ngOnInit** function:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

   this.store.dispatch(new basketActions.Load());

    this.basket$ = this.store.pipe(
        select(fromBasket.getBasket)
    );

    this.nettoTotal$ = this.basket$.pipe(
        map((basket) => basket.lines),
        reduce( ??? )
    );
}
```

How can I use the reduce function so I get a correct total in my view ?

Update:

This does work however:

```
this.nettoTotal$ = this.basket$.pipe(
  map((basket) => {
     if (basket) {
        return basket.lines;
     } else {
        return [];
     }
  }),
  map((lines) => {
            let total = 0;
            for (const line of lines) {
                const val = Math.round((line.bestelaantal * line.nettoprijs * 100) / 100);
                total = total + val;
            }

            return total;
        })
    );
```

Update 2:

This code works when I directly call the method of my service which returns an Observable of IBasket:

```
this.nettoTotal$ = this.basketService.getBasket().pipe(
            map((basket) => basket.lines),
            map((lines) => lines.map((line) => line.nettoprijs * line.bestelaantal).reduce(
                (accumulator, linePrice) => accumulator + linePrice,
                0
            ))
        );
```

This code DOES not work when I use the observable coming from my store:

```
this.nettoTotal$ = this.basket$.pipe(
            map((basket) => basket.lines),
            map((lines) => lines.map((line) => line.nettoprijs * line.bestelaantal).reduce(
                (accumulator, linePrice) => accumulator + linePrice,
                0
            ))
        );
```

Comment: In that case, try to `subscribe` to the `basket$` Observable and log the response to the console to check what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem myself.  It had nothing to do with the reduce operator at all. At the moment I executed the reduce function the data for the basket was not yet fetched from the backend.  In other words, the store had not yet received the data from my LoadSuccess action.
So I ended up adding a new selector to my reducer to calculate the netTotal.

```
export const getNetTotal = createSelector(
    getBasketFeatureState,
    (state) => {
        if (!state.basket) {
            return 0;
        }
        let total = state.basket.lines.map((line) => (line.amountOrdered * line.price)).reduce(
            (total, amount) => total + amount,
            0
        );
        total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;

        return total;
    }
);
```

The ngOnInit function now looks like this and everything works:

```
this.store.dispatch(new basketActions.Load());

this.basket$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromBasket.getBasket));
this.nettoTotal$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromBasket.getNetTotal));
```

Answer (score 0):

RxJs' `reduce` function works similar to the `Array.prototype.reduce` function. You give it a function for handling the reduce and a seed value and when the `Observable` completes then the reduced value is emitted from the stream. Here is how you can calculate the sum:

```js
this.nettoTotal$ = this.basket$.pipe(
  map((basket) => basket.lines),
  reduce((total, count) => total + count, 0)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `map` is returning the lines and each line will contain `unitsOrdered` and `price`, you can introduce another round of `map` and directly return the `price` * `unitsOrdered` from there, and then accumulate it in the `reduce` operator.

Give this a try:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

   this.store.dispatch(new basketActions.Load());

    this.basket$ = this.store.pipe(
        select(fromBasket.getBasket)
    );

    this.nettoTotal$ = this.basket$.pipe(
        map(basket => basket.lines),
        map(lines => lines.map(line => line.price * line.unitsOrdered)),
        reduce(
          (accumulator, linePrice) => accumulator + linePrice,
          0
        )
    );
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-map-reduce-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: thx for the response.  I tried it out but it does not give a total.

Comment: @pdw, are you getting any errors? I just noticed that there was a space between `line.` and  `unitsOrdered`. I've fixed it. Please check again and let me know if that works. If it still doesn't work, could you please let me know what exactly are you getting on `subscribe`ing to the `Observable`, or whether you're getting any errors.

Comment: I do not get any errors.  The total is just blank on the screen.  However, I only subscribe in my view with the async pipe. I updated my question with code that does work.

Comment: Would it possible for you to replicate this on StackBlitz with a minimal replicable code sample?

Comment: That would be difficult for me. I use Nativescript with Angular on an ios simulator and I have never used Stackblitz before.

Comment: @pdw, I've added a Sample StackBlitz for your ref. I've assumed the format of `basket$` as given in the service. Please have a look. Hope you get a better idea of what I'm suggesting once you have a look at the StackBlitz.

Comment: I begin to see the light...
I see in Stackblitz that you are returning a stream of totals.  I actually only want one value : the total for the basket as the sum of all lines.  When I change this.basket$ into this.basketService.getBasket() (which is what actually gets called by the dispatch of my Load action) I see the same output as in Stackblitz.